# Principal ideal rings that are not integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

In the usual definition, a principal ideal domain $R$ is also assumed to be an integral domain. However, the property that every ideal is generated by a single element does not seem to immediately imply that the ring is integral. Is this correct and if so:

> Do there exist rings where every ideal is generated by a single element and has zero divisors?

I am most interested in the case where $R$ is commutative with unity, but don't mind examples where these properties don't hold.

Also, assuming there are examples, is there any reason why we make this assumption?

Comment: What about $\Bbb Z_4$?

Comment: Principal ideal *rings* are of course studied. The minimal example is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  Such rings are called [principal ideal rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring). An example of such a ring would be $K[x]/(x^2)$, where $K$ is any field.

In fact, a theorem of Hungerford states that any principal ideal ring is the direct product of quotients of principal ideal domains.

Comment: One can find a link to Hungerford's result in the [Wikipedia article on principal ideal rings.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_ring)